# winforms DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, ComboBox not clickable when DataPropertyName is set

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have DataGridView with DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with datasource binding, when I bind DataPropertyName of DataGridView, **ComboBox becomes not clickable.**

```
dgFMS.ReadOnly = false;
```

Correct DataPropertyName is bind with each row but I can not choose from drop-down

```
BindingSource _bsCats2 = new BindingSource();
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn catCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
_bsCats2.DataSource = CategoryManager.Categories.Select(x => new { 
    Key = x.ParentWithName.ToLowerInvariant(), 
    Value = x.Id })
    .ToList();
catCol.DataSource = _bsCats2;
catCol.DataPropertyName = "catID";
catCol.DisplayMember = "Key";
catCol.ValueMember = "Value";
catCol.Width = 250;
catCol.ReadOnly = false;
dgFMS.Columns.Add(catCol);
dgFMS.ReadOnly = false;
```

I am also implementing dgFMS_EditingControlShowing as well

```
private void dgFMS_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (cb != null)
    {
        cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
        cb.SelectedValueChanged -= new EventHandler(CmbCat_SelectedIndexChanged);
        cb.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(CmbCat_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found problem with binding data

DataPropertyName = "catID" was read-only property with only getter without setter like this

```
public int catID
    {
        get
        {
            return CategoryManager.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(SubCategory, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Id;
        }
    }
```

By adding setter of the property solved the problem.